# HTTParty Post Some parts JSON encoded, some not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am trying to send a post request to a separate app where I need to send a matching signature that is not json encoded and the data, which is json encoded. I keep getting errors when I try to do this, so I'm just not understanding how to format it, and I can't find any examples on SO or their documentation (or anywhere else on the web).

```
signature = create_signature

result = HTTParty.post("weburl.com/file/to/post_to.php",
        :body => {[ signature, 
                  :data => { :timestamp => @message.created_at,
                    :url => company.request_host,
                    :name => @message.name,
                    :email => @message.email,
                    :phone => @message.phone,
                    :product => @message.service,
                    :comments => @message.message
                  }.to_json
                 ]},
        :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        :verify => false )
```

The error I'm getting currently is syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => ]}, ^

I've also tried without the arrays, without the data array, etc.

How do I format this to properly submit this info?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your .to_json to the end of the object.

```
  :body => {[ signature, 
                      :data => { :timestamp => @message.created_at,
                        :url => company.request_host,
                        :name => @message.name,
                        :email => @message.email,
                        :phone => @message.phone,
                        :product => @message.service,
                        :comments => @message.message
                      }
                     ].to_json},
```

Comment: won't that encode signature as json? That's the part I'm trying to avoid.